# laravel Hasmany where id or another_id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

how can i do that with function in model?

```
Select * from friends where (user_id = 22 or content_id = 22) and type=2 and situation = 1;
```

i try that, but it gives error;

```
public function friends() { 
    return $this->hasMany('Friends',function ($query) {
        $query->where('content_id', $this->attributes['id']);
        $query->orWhere('user_id',$this->attributes['id']);
    })->where('type',2)->where('situation',1)->orderBy('id','DESC');
}
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @lukasgeiter i'm using this way

    @ foreach ($users->friends as $friend)
        {{$friend->id}}
    @ endforeach

error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Comment: Shouldn't you call `friends` on a single user model?

Comment: i'm calling friends for a user.
$users  = User::where('username',$username)->where('type','1')->first();

Comment: Okay, was just a bit confused because of the plural form of user. Your code generally looks fine. Can you just delete the `{{ $friend->id }}` part to make sure we're searching at the right spot ?

Comment: You can't setup such relation if you want it to work as expected. What you've tried could be accomplished in a way, but won't work for eager load/lazy loading for multiple models, so I suggest you don't do it at all. Better describe what you want to achieve with this and probably there will be a better way for you.

Comment: still same error, i think problem is in "hasMany". can i use hasMany('Friends',function ($query) ...) in hasMany? Before that i was using hasMany('Friends', 'user_id'), but now i must add there "user_id or content_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is your model name 'Friends' or just 'Friend'? Assuming you're following convention and using the singular tense for your model names, this should work:

```
return $this->hasMany('Friend')->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('content_id', $this->attributes['id']);
    $query->orWhere('user_id',$this->attributes['id']);
})->where('type',2)->where('situation',1)->orderBy('id','DESC');
```

in other words, add your additional query parameters following the hasMany() relationship, not as a closure for the second argument.